# Python - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (17,90) (17,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, scipy-optimize

I am trying to implement logistic regression with regularization in Python using `optimize.minimize` from the SciPy library. Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

l = 0.1 # lambda

def sigmoid(z):

    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

def cost_function_logit(theta, X, y, l):

    h = sigmoid(X @ theta)

    # cost

    J = -1 / m * (y.T @ np.log(h)
                 + (1 - y).T @ np.log(1 - h)) \
                 + l / (2 * m) * sum(theta[1:] ** 2)

    # gradient

    a = 1 / m * X.T @ (h - y)
    b = l / m * theta
    grad = a + b
    grad[0] = 1 / m * sum(h - y)

    return J, grad

data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')

X = data.drop(columns = ['healthy'])
m, n = X.shape
X = X.to_numpy()
X = np.hstack([np.ones([m, 1]), X])

y = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['healthy'])
y = y.to_numpy()

initial_theta = np.zeros([n + 1, 1])

options = {'maxiter': 400}
res = optimize.minimize(cost_function_logit,
                        initial_theta,
                        (X, y, l),
                        jac = True,
                        method = 'TNC',
                        options = options)
```

An error occurs on the line where I use `optimize.minimize`. The last two lines of the error are as follows:

`grad = a + b`

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (17,90) (17,)`

I have checked the type and dimensions of X, y and theta, and they seem correct to me.

```
>>> type(X)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(y)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(theta)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> X.shape
(90, 17)
>>> y.shape
(90, 1)
>>> theta.shape
(17, 1)
```

The error says a is a (17,90) matrix but based on my calculations it should be a (17,1) vector. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Alas, cost_function_logit is completely unreadable. I, for one don’t know if * or @ has higher priority. Use temporary variables for subexpressions and your code will be both more readable and you’ll be able to better pinpoint where the mistake is.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for your reply. I don't think priority matters as m is a scalar. Also, I forgot to mention that the issue only occurs when I use optimize.minimize. The cost function works fine in other settings. The problem seems to be with the definition of grad in the cost function. I edited my code to show this - I split grad into two parts, a and b. The error says that a is (17,90) while b is (17,). To me, both should be (17,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, `optimize.minimize` didn't like that y and theta had shapes (90,1) and (17,1), respectively. I converted their shape to (90,) and (17,) and the error message went away.

In terms of code, I changed

```py
initial_theta = np.zeros([n + 1, 1])
```

to just this:

```py
initial_theta = np.zeros([n + 1])
```

and I added the following line:

```py
y = np.reshape(y, [m])
```

Thanks to those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `a` are 90 dimensional vectors, whereas the elements of `b` are numbers. I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to add vectors, they need to have the same shape. If you want to add the thing in `b` to each element in `a` row-wise you can do

```
grad = a + np.stack((b,) * a.shape[1], axis=-1)
```

but I'm assuming you just are messing up constructing `a`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand why the error says a is (17, 90) when based on my calculations it should be (17, 1). At the bottom of my initial post I verified that X is (90,17), y is (90,1) and theta is (17,1). Therefore, a = 1 / m * X.T @ (sigmoid(X @ theta) - y) should be a (17,1) vector, just like b, shouldn't it? (m is a scalar.) When I run the cost function on its own it works fine and all arrays have the expected dimensions; the issue only comes up when I use optimize.minimize.